# Trigger a function on the start of a new day in javascript

Tags: javascript

Everyday I need to trigger a function on the start of a new day. How do I do that in Javascript?
I have a desktop application made on electron js. I am logging necessary logs in a log file.
I am creating new log file every new day.
But i need to zip log file every new day. So i want to trigger a function which is used for zipping log file on the start of a new day.

Comment: Where is this JS running? What's the context of this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have added more details in the post. Please have a look at it

Comment: I think you are interested in CRON jobs

Comment: If you are using MacOS, you could use [crontab](https://crontab.guru) instead. (you can probably find cron for other OSes as well, I'm just not aware of how).

Comment: it has to be independent of OS

Comment: node-cron will help

Answer (score 0):

You have the following solutions, its depend on how your applications works

- Your app is running on servers that you control -> Use cron
- Your app is always online -> if its nodejs search for cronjob in npm packages, if its pure js work witch setTimeout/setInterval
- Your app is reachable from outside -> Run a cronjob on a remote server to ping your application, or simply set a daily job on zappier/powerautomate to ping your application
- Your app is not reachable from outside, not always online, and you dont want cron -> Manage logs when starting applications + use solution 1 when its oline

Answer (score 0):

We have two options here:

- Server Side [server is always up and running]
- Clinet Side [web app needs to be executed/opened by an end user]

in server side, we have a very good package called [`node-schedule`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

but on the client side, we can use setTimeout and some normal time calculations to call a function after certain amount of time like given example.

```js
const currDate = new Date();

// this will give the current time in ms
const currTime = currDate.getTime();

// increase the date by 1
currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 1);

// set hours, mins, seconds to the 0 [as setHours can accepts (hours, mins, seconds, miliseconds), we can pass all the parameters at once]
currDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

// now currDate holds the time for midnight
const midnightTime = currDate.getTime();

// create a setTimeout function for the time difference
const diff = midnightTime - currTime;
console.log(`Code will be triggered after: ${diff}ms`);
setTimeout(() => {
  // your code goes here
}, diff);
```